# Calculating various statistics of a bivariate distribtion (in R)

Tags: r, probability, probability-density

I have a joint probability table for which I would like to calculate basic statistics, e.g.: E(x), standard deviation, covariance, correllation coefficient, etc.

I'm new to R and I've been able to figure out how to do all of these things manually, however I'd like learn a more efficient way of doing these calculations.

These are two soccer teams joint probability distribution of scoring 0-3 goals, hence the row and column names are numbers such that the margin sums multiplied by the column/row header, give the expected value of x or y.

```r
#fill matrix by rows  
bivdist <- matrix( c(.14, .11, .09, .1, .12, .1, .05, .02, .09, .07, .04, .01, .03, .02, .01, 0), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE) 


#Give names to the rows and columns  
dimnames(bivdist) <- list( c("0", "1", "2", "3" ), ("0", "1", "2", "3"))
```

This is how I implemented a portion of the tasks, for example:

```r
#get the margin sums  
msumx<-marginSums(bivdist, 1);msumx;

#calculate expected value  
EVx<-msumx[1]*0+msumx[2]*1+msumx[3]*2+msumx[4]*3; EVx;

#calculate variance  
varx<-(0-EVx)^2*msumx[1]+(1-EVx)^2*msumx[2]+(2-EVx)^2*msumx[3]+(3-EVx)^2*msumx[4];varx;

#calculate standard deviation  
sigmax<-sqrt(varx);sigmax;
```

To get Covariance of XY, I found a way that's a bit
cleaner:

```r
X <- 0:3; Y <- 0:3;

joint_pmf<-matrix(c(.14, .11, .09, .1, .12, .1, .05, .02, .09, .07, .04, .01, 
                    .03, .02, .01, 0), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE)  
mu_X <- rowSums(joint_pmf) %*% X;  
mu_Y<- colSums(joint_pmf) %*% Y;  
cov_XY <- X %*% joint_pmf %*% Y - mu_X * mu_Y;cov_XY;  
corXY<-cov_XY/(sigmax*sigmay);corXY;
```

What's the more efficient, cleaner way of doing all of the above?